# HP Quality Center API + ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-2.0

Has anyone ever used ASP or ASP.NET to connect to HPQC via the API? Where can I find some examples of this interaction? Any direction on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess by looking into the QC Open Test Architecture API documentation will do. There are lots of examples based in VB. The only difference when implementing it on ASP is that you will need to install the QC API where you web server will be executing the Active Server Pages.

Comment: Thanks... The answer is a little late but appreciated because I am sure that some one else will find this information useful somewhere down the road. I did exactly what you mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

The Open Test Architecture (OTA) API is supplied as a COM library in OTAClient.dll (which is included when you install the HP Quality Center Client Side Setup Add-in -- QCExplorer.)  You can reference the DLL as a COM object with .NET wrapper.